# Does a subscription throw an error if i do not catch it?

Tags: angular, typescript, error-handling, rxjs, subject

I'm using `Subject` of `rxjs` and, every time I write my code for catch an error and do nothing with it except throwing it. But I don't know if it's good or totaly useless, because maybe if I do not catch it, the error will be throw by default. Can you help me please ? I can't find any answer online.

this is an example :

```js
    import {Subject} from 'rxjs';

    /* ... */

    public someObs : Subject<SomeType> = new Subject<SomeType>

    /* ... */

    ngOnInit(): void {
        this.someObs.subscribe((elem: SomeType) => {
            /* some code */
        }, (err) => {
            throw err;
        });
    }
```

May be I can just do this :

```js
    ngOnInit(): void {
        this.someObs.subscribe((elem: SomeType) => {
            /* some code */
        });
    }
```

Comment: Just try it yourself: https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-prdead

Answer (score 0):

Instead of throw err; you can try to log it in console

```
ngOnInit(): void {
        this.someObs.subscribe((elem: SomeType) => {
            /* some code */
        }, function(error) { 
               console.log("Error - " + error.error.text); });
    }
```

Comment: But it's not what i want. I think, As an error it can be like this `console.error(error.message)` but it's the same result than `throw error`.

Comment: Ok I think I kind of understand what you mean. As far I know the stream gets killed if an error occurs and if its not handled. Please see below link that I bumped into and see if it helps https://medium.com/@benlesh/on-the-subject-of-subjects-in-rxjs-2b08b7198b93 . If not lets see if someone has any better explanation.

Answer (score 0):

In rxjs error handling, a stream can error out only once. The stream will not emit any further values after an error is thrown. That means if one particular stream errors out, you will not be able to use it anymore.

You can import Observable throwError  using:

```
import { throwError } from 'rxjs';
```

and handle your error in a meaningfull way as follows:

```
if (error.status === 404)
    return throwError( new NotFoundError(error) )
```